# Length array in array

Tags: php, arrays

if I have an array like this:

```
$array = array(
     1,
     2,
     3,
     ["thing1", "thing2", "thing3"]
);
```

how do I check what the lenght is of the array in the array ( ["thing1", "thing2", "thing3"] )?

Comment: $length = array_length($array[3]);

Comment: Is your array always in this format? Is the nested array always the last element? Can there be more elements within the array before it? There's a lot of variables that could come into play that will stop all the solutions provided so far from working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [Array Count function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) `count` or [sizeof](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sizeof.php) function.

try below code:

```
$array = array(
    1,
    2,
    3,
    ["thing1", "thing2", "thing3"]
);

echo count($array[3]); //out put 3
echo sizeof($array[3]); //out put 3
```

Comment: Out of the two `count` is probably preferable over `sizeof` if you do go with this method, `sizeof` is just an alias of count, and can cause confusion for some programmers since it doesn't do what many expect it to.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) function:

```
echo count($array[3]);
```

However if the array you want to get the length is not always in this same position you could do something like this:

```
foreach ($array as $element) {
    if (is_array($element) {
        echo count($element);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use [count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) function here.

```
$array = array(
    1,
    2,
    3,
    ["thing1", "thing2", "thing3"]
);
echo count($array[3]); //out put 3
```

> Though you can use sizeof but again sizeof() is an alias for count(),
>   they work the same.

You may use [sizeof](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sizeof.php) like this..

```
echo sizeof($array[3]); //out put 3
```